# Why $\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\log tdt =-\gamma$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is $$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\log tdt?$$

Plugging into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty+e%5E%7B-t%7D%5Clog+tdt) yields that it's $-\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. How can we get it? Maybe by some contour integration?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant will explain where this constant appears (a lot of places).

Comment: Take a look at the right hand side of the page, under *Related*, and you'll see there several questions asking the exact same thing you're asking. Click on them, and read their answers.